# Robot framework, generic function to give name to a list

Tags: robotframework, generic-list

I'm trying to create a keyword that will export a list as a suite variable, but I can't figure out how to pass a name to turn into a variable name.

```
    *** Test Cases ***
Get Ref
    ${list} =   Create List     k   l   m   n  e
    Rename List   myName  ${list}
    log     @{myName}


*** Keywords ***
Rename List
    [Arguments]  ${name}    ${values}
    log     first: ${values[1]}
    @{name}=     Create List  ${values[1]}    ${values[3]}
    set suite variable  @{name}
```

The keyword takes a string and a list, creates a smaller list and exports it with the name string provided.
As a use-case, you want a generic function that can take values from a dropdown list on a webpage and return you just item 1, 3, and 5 as a new list with the name you provide.  This way you could call it multiple times with different names, exporting different lists that you could use later.
Is there any way to make this work?

Comment: instead of `rename list    myName    ${list}`, why not just use `${myName}=    rename list    ${list}` or just `${myName}=  create list   @{list}`? What's the point of passing the name ot a keyword?

Comment: I want to be able to call it multiple times, so you could have multiple lists created within one suite, each with a unique name.  The first option you suggest is a workable solution, the 2nd one doesn't allow any manipulation within the function (splitting, setting suite variables, etc.) I was hoping for something more elegant, but maybe I'm getting stuck on what I want, not what works.

Comment: Correction (since it's too late to edit), no it doesn't work for me, since I want to call Set Suite Variable on my new list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to do what you want, if I understand the question correctly:

```
*** keywords ***
rename list
    [Arguments]    ${name}    ${values}
    ${new}=    create list    @{values}
    set suite variable    ${${name}}  ${new}
```

Comment: This works great.  I tried using the ${${name}} method before, but not like this.  The only change I made was to use `set suite variable    @{${name}}  @{new}`     Thanks!